# Trying to mimic data usage through certain apps

Tags: applications, mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, data-monitoring, data-plan

my current data plan has unlimited usage for only certain apps;
Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, YouTube, WhatsApp, Facebook Messenger, and Telegram.

Any other form of data usage isn't unlimited taking from my limited data pool.

Would it be possible to mimic the data usage of a HotSpot to go through any one of these apps.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as my home internet is out for the next couple of mounths :)

Comment: Data plans with free traffic for certain apps usually uses the target server (e.g. DNS name) to determine if it belongs to an app with free traffic or not. So you won't succeed unless one of the white listed servers provides an proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand your concern but there's nothing you can do for this. Your telecom operator is doing the whitelisting (of those apps) on their end; there's nothing you can do as a client.